# Raspberry PI u-boot reports "no partition table"

Tags: raspberry-pi, u-boot

I have built the very latest u-boot release and placed the image on a Raspberry PI. After boot, I get this error message:

U-Boot 2013.10 (Oct 24 2013 - 09:35:44)

```
DRAM:  448 MiB
WARNING: Caches not enabled
MMC:   bcm2835_sdhci: 0
```

Using default environment

```
In:    serial
Out:   lcd
Err:   lcd
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
mmc0 is current device
** No partition table - mmc 0 **
U-Boot>
```

Obviously, u-boot failed to mount the file system.
Can this be related to some mmc related setting as access speed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it has nothing to do with programming. There are [plenty](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/) of [other](http://forum.xbmc.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=166) RaspPi [forums](http://forum.xbmc.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=166) out there. Why not try one of those?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If the error relates to a custom kernel & can be fixed in the compiler/linker options, then it is on-topic.

Comment: porting uboot to raspi is on topic, but there is a lack of what I have tried (show the code), results, expectations...

Comment: Try to enable more debugging in config.mk with setting DBGFLAGS= -g  -DDEBUG. Do you have partitions on the MMC? Can you get useful information about the MMC using mmcinfo?